# pass to a function an object which is an instance of a subclass of the type accepted by the function

Tags: php, oop, function, parameter-passing

is there any way who let the code below works?

```
public function my_function(My_Class $arg){  ....   }

public class My_Sub_Class extends My_Class { ...  }

//NOW
$my_object = new My_Sub_Class();

my_function($my_object);
```

I've Edited some write errors

Comment: please clarify the question. What is your problem?

Comment: Well, if it "doesn't work", then we can't tell what it's supposed to do from the code. Because the code "doesn't work", so it is broken, which means that it does not _actually_ represent what you wanted to do. So we don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class My_Sub_Class extends My_Class() { }
```

should be

```
public class My_Sub_Class extends My_Class { }
```

Also, I'm not sure what `$my_object = new My_Sub_Class(){ .... }` is supposed to be. A `My_Sub_Class` is not a function!

---

Fixing these errors, adding a definition of `My_Class` to your testcase, and removing the `public` prefixes (because your example had no surrounding class definition), I end up with the following, which [works just fine](http://codepad.org/kdU4ay4q):

```
<?php
class My_Class {}
class My_Sub_Class extends My_Class {}

function my_function(My_Class $arg){ echo "my_function"; }

$my_object = new My_Sub_Class();
my_function($my_object);
?>
```

---

Take a look at [the `extends` keyword in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php).

In fact, take a look at *every feature you use* in the manual, if you can't get something to "work".

Answer (score 0):

You code works just fine (that is, passing a subclass to function that has a superclass typehint). Here's my code, verified to work on PHP 5.3.3:

```
<?php
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {}
function quu(Foo $a) { return $a; }

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

var_dump(quu($foo));
var_dump(quu($bar));
```

Of course, you have a syntax error on your second and third line. But that has nothing to do with your question...

Comment: This was not his code. The syntax error has _everything_ to do with his question. It's the reason his code "doesn't works".

Answer (score 0):

Since the child class extends parent class, it has to have all the properties and methods of the parent class. Because of that, you do not have to fear - your function will receive and work with objects of all the child classes as well.
You have an error in your third line - after initializing an object you do not need curly brackets.